# Как растянуть кнопки по всей ширине Hbox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Хочу, что бы нижний ряд кнопок был по всей ширине Hbox. Для этого прописал :  maxWidth="-Infinity" , у каждой кнопки. Но это не сработало.
Подскажите, что я сделал не так и как сделать правильно???[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

После данных манипуляций перезагрузить проект в SceneBuilder. [image: FXML] Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044487/javafx-fit-child-elements-to-hbox-width.

Но пишут что подобные манипуляции лучше производить из кода.